# GA Api V3 with Service account auth

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics

Last week I created two reporting projects no problems at all , in total now I got 3. I want to make the fourth for a client and I'm getting 403 error code out of nowhere. I followed the same procedures as the last project no success.

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
```

User does not have any Google Analytics account. [403]

**Errors**

> Message[User does not have any Google Analytics account.] Location[ -
>   ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]

I even deleted the project in Google Console api three times get the service account email that the provide I added in Google, I done it as Administrator as user  nothing, I searched in the internet and I found that a lot of people having this problem.

All the solutions was related to set the service email account to user instead of admin, the strange thing is the other projects I got this email as admin in Google Analytics and in the console as owner (team tab) and its working perfect no problem. This one nothing so far. What else could I do ?